# How to create a role with discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to make a discord bot using discord.js, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to create a role that **works in 2018**. All the ones I can find that work, no longer work as they have removed the referenced function.
In https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role there is no mention of a createRole("role", "roleName"); type function.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `Role` does not have the method to create a new role, you must look at the `Guild` class for that. Here is a link to the documentation for the method: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createRole. Feel free to comment back if you have any questions!

**Edit: As of discord.js v12, `createRole` no longer exists**, please refer to cecomp64's answer above on creating new roles with the new `RoleManager` object.

Answer (score 18):

Guild.createRole does not appear to exist in 2020.  Instead, it seems that you can get a reference to a RoleManager object via the property Guild.roles, and then call create on the RoleManager object:

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create

From their docs:

```js
// Create a new role with data and a reason
guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Super Cool People',
    color: 'BLUE',
  },
  reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```