# Create a role with Discord JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord JS bot which is supposed to have a mute function that assigns a role to a member so they can't text.

I tried looking all over the web for how to create a role (even the Discord JS documentation) but to no avail.

I've tried the code below but it doesn't work (pulled straight from https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create).

```js
guild.roles.create({
        data: {
            name: 'Super Cool People',
            color: 'BLUE',
        },
        reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
    })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a role with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53329343/how-to-create-a-role-with-discord-js)

Comment: Funny thing is that I looked at that exact post. But no, it didn't work.

Comment: By didn't work, do you mean it threw an error or just didn't add the role?

Comment: If this is being triggered by a command, try message.member.guild.roles.create({...})

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that `guild` is not defined within your code. `roles` is a property of [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles), so you need a [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles) class to access [`RoleManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager) and create a [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role).

---

If your code is executed within a command, you can use `message.guild` to get the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild), otherwise, you'll need to get the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) manually.

Here's a simple example of how to use it:

## First Scenario

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return false;
    if (message.author.id !== message.guild.ownerID) return false;

    message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
            name: "Muted",
            permissions: [],
            color: "RED"
        },
        reason: "Created the mute role."
    }).catch(console.log)
});
```

## Second Scenario

```js
const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("1234567890123456789");

Guild.roles.create({
    data: {
        name: "Muted",
        permissions: [],
        color: "RED"
    },
    reason: "Created the mute role."
}).catch(console.log)
```

Comment: Well this unfortunately doesn't work. I copy/pasted your code (adjusting for variables of course) but it threw an error: `message.guild.roles.create({` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

as long as you have a role manager you should have the create function according to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager)

so my advice to fix this issue is see where it goes wrong. I've done it with the createGuild event in typeScript. this will create the roles when the bot joins a new guild.

```
client.on('guildCreate', async guild => {
  await guild.roles.create({ data: { name: 'roleName' } });
});
```

also be aware that you need high enough permissions to actually create a role.

ps: providing errors when you have an error would be useful (the full error)

Answer (score 0):

If you will try to do guild.create.roles the console will give you an error with message: `guild <= is not defined!`

You need to write `message.guild.create.roles` not `the guild.create.roles`, after this, you will get the created role.

Example code creating the role, with the "debug messages":

```
message.channel.send('creating a role')
        message.guild.roles.create({
            data: {
                name: 'Testing Role',
                color: 'GREY'
            },
            reason: 'Stackoverflow.com - created for user14470589'
        })
        .then((res => {
            message.channel.send(`debug result:\n${res}`)
        })).catch((err => {
            message.channel.send(`error:\n${err}`)
        }))
```